# Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении или не нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

*Я не привык экономить(,) вот и оставил свет включенным.*

Answer (score 2):

Без знака препинания здесь не обойтись. Можно поставить **запятую**, интонационно отделяющую вторую часть предложения, а можно и **тире:**

***Я не привык экономить – вот и оставил свет включенным.***

> Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен.

Смысловые отношения понятны: *почему я оставил свет включенным? – потому что не привык экономить.* Причина указана в первой части предложения. По аналогии с бессоюзным сложным предложением ставим тире.

> Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится **тире**, если в ней содержится следствие, результат либо вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой части (между частями можно вставить слова *поэтому, тогда* и т. п.)...

Также тире ставится перед словами ***вот, это, так, таков***, начинающими конструкции присоединительного характера.

**Пример** из Нацкорпуса русского языка:
*Наверное, дом у нас был закрыт, а ждать меня с уроков дядя Ваня не мог ― вот и оставил в раздевалке.* [Валентин Распутин. Уроки французского (1973)]

Источники: [**Интонационное тире**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94), [**Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151) (Розенталь).

Comment: Александр, я согласна с вами, что без знака здесь не обойтись, что видно по интонации. Но самое простое решение – это поставить запятую: «Я не привык экономить, вот и оставил свет включенным». Но как определить грамматику предложения и объяснить выбор знака? Мне этот вопрос показался любопытным в таком плане: какие решения в принципе могут предложить пользователи. Предложение не похоже на БСП, отношения между сказуемыми  выглядят как однородные. Можно сравнить: «Я не привык экономить и поэтому оставил свет включенным».  Здесь также обозначена причина, но даже запятой нет.

Comment: @Sharon, я чуть подправил начало ответа. В предложении  с  ***и поэтому***, конечно, знак не нужен, грамматика другая.  А в предложении из вопроса ***вот и*** задает присоединение.

Comment: А *Hanu* так и не реагирует на мои призывы, все три плюса за ответы на его вопросы – мои.

Comment: Hanu даже незарегистрированный участник, какой с него спрос.  Как вариант, можно не отвечать на вопросы.  Присоединительная конструкция? Но она имеет явное причинное значение, две части предложения тесно связаны между собой. Если вы будете делать грамматический разбор, то это БСП или однородные члены? Также статус ВОТ И надо обозначить. А общем, не хватает грамматической ясности.  Мне кажется, что здесь однородные сказуемые, а  ВОТ И – скорее пояснительный союз со значением причины.

Comment: Что-то вроде этого, но хотелось бы сослаться на какой-нибудь источник. Наречие «поэтому» дифференцирует однородные члены, связанные соединительным союзом И, здесь тоже похожая ситуация. Но если особо не заморачиваться, то условно можно сказать: да, это присоединительная конструкция

Comment: Пример с запятой: У меня тут же мелькнула мысль: наверное, скучает со своей женой, вот и звонит  с дурацкими воспоминаниями и разговорами. Заданное предложение мало похоже на БСП, там явно один субъект действия и два сказуемых.

Comment: Конечно же, я не исключаю вариант с запятой и не говорю, что это БСП, просто провожу аналогию с ним.

Comment: И все-таки  окончательный вывод о грамматике предложения я не могу пока сделать.

Answer (score 0):

*Я не привык экономить, **вот и** оставил свет включенным.*

Запятая в этом предложении нужна, также можно поставить интонационное тире.
Здесь **однородные сказуемые** «привык экономить» (составное глагольное) и «оставил включенным» (составное именное), которые связаны союзом **ВОТ И**.

Этот союз можно отнести к **подчинительным союзам** – вариант союза "и вот поэтому" со значением причины.  В этом случае запятая ставится.
Сравнить:  *Он приехал, хотя и был очень занят.*

Из словаря: **ВОТ, частица**. 8. В составе сложных союзов: (и) вот почему, (и) вот оттого, (и) вот поэтому.