# Может ли одно наречие относиться сразу к двум глаголам?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, однородные-члены, наречия

Является ли следующее предложение корректным с точки зрения норм русского языка?
*Он пожелал хорошо сдать экзамены и **провести** лето.*

Иначе говоря, допустимо ли опустить второе наречие (*хорошо провести*) во избежание некоторой тавтологии?

Comment: "Хорошо" — это наречие.

Comment: Да, разумеется. =D

Comment: Видимо, у меня всё совсем плохо. Тем не менее, буду рад любой помощи по теме вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Желательно написать так: *Он пожелал (что?) **успешно** сдать экзамены и **хорошо** провести лето.*

Здесь мы имеем два однородных дополнения на основе инфинитивов.

Поэтому в данном случае каждый глагол должен иметь свое наречие, а во избежание тавтологии надо использовать синонимы.

Comment: А как отличить составное глагольное сказуемое от сказуемого с дополнениями? Вот никак этого не могу определить "на глаз". // Кстати, проанализировав выдачу Нацкорпуса, я могу сказать, что наречие может принадлежать двум существительным, если они образуют как бы смысловое целое: *При каждом повороте головы её волосы красиво вздымаются и опадают*.

Comment: @ 
Nektoid
  Вероятно, возможны предложения, в которых одно наречие относится к обоим глаголам, как в вашем примере. А отличить составное глагольное сказуемое несложно: в этом случае вспомогательный глагол и инфинитив относятся к субъекту действия, например: Я хочу успешно сдать экзамены и хорошо провести лето. Если же инфинитив относится к другому лицу, то это уже другой член предложения.

Comment: Отвечаю не сразу, очень плохая связь, сеть постоянно пропадает.

Comment: понятно, спасибо. Постараюсь научиться различать)

Comment: @ Nektoid А чо вы думаете об этом предложении https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470441/Нужна-ли-запятая-в-следующем-предложении-или-не-нужна

Comment: Да, можно сказать, ничего. Запятая перед "вот и" (или даже тире) определённо слышится, но почему — не знаю.

Comment: @Nektoid Понятно... У меня тоже была такая первая реация: запятая нужна, а почему – не знаю. Потом в словаре нашла для частицы ВОТ: 8. В составе сложных союзов: (и) вот почему, (и) вот оттого,  (и) вот поэтому.

Comment: Как-то и вопрос, и Ваш ответ *пропустились*. Теперь всё поправлено.